# Experiencing issue with robot framework while executing on windows operating system

Tags: exception, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Experiencing issue with robot framework in windows operating system.
Code:

```
*** settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** variables ***

*** test cases ***
This is simple test case
    [documentation]  Google test
    [tags]  Regression

    open Browser  https://www.google.com  chrome  
    close Browser

*** keywords ***
```

```
Error: [WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download ChromeDriver here: https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Then either add it to your system PATH( Inside system environment variable) you can search it using windows search.

Or you can specify the location directly via executable_path

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
```